# Page exit confirmation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am having a couple of problems with my rails app. When a user enters data and then attempts to leave the page via any means (except submit), I want it to prompt them to confirm leaving the page. This is the code I have so far and it works to an extent. If the user fills in some data then clicks 'submit' they are still prompted to confirm leaving the page. If they choose to stay on the page, and then click 'submit' again it will work as expected.

```
var clean;
var submitted = false;

$(function(){
  clean = $("form").serialize();
});

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  $("form").submit(function() {
    submitted = true;
  });
  var dirty = $("form").serialize();
  if (dirty != clean && !submitted) {
    return "You have unsaved data that will be lost if you leave the page.";
  }
};
```

I'd also like the prompt to occur when a user attempts to follow one of the links on the page (not just closing it etc). I'm using jquery-turbolinks but it still doesn't seem to pick those events up.

Any help with either of these problems would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  

  var isEdit  = false;  

  $('input').change(function() {  
    isEdit = true;  
  });  

  function checkIsEdit() {  
    if(isEdit)  
      return "You have modified some content. Please save this form.";  
  }  

  window.onbeforeunload = checkIsEdit;  
  $(document).submit(function(){
    isEdit = false;
  });
});  
</script>
```

(Based on http://www.webstuffshare.com/2010/03/code-snippet-jquery-confirm-before-exit/)